# Weird Textbox tab issue in asp.net page using 3.5 framework

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, textbox, internet-explorer-8

I have a crazy issue when tabbing from one textbox to another.

This happens on a webpage which contains about 20+ textboxes, and this happens on the same textboxes, and I have no idea what is the cause.

When the cursor is in a textfield, I type in a value, hit tab, the focus goes to the next textbox, I hit tab, the focus stays in the same textbox, I have to hit tab again to go to the 3rd textbox.

This is annoying because the user is types their values, hits tab, starts typing values for the next txtbox, only for the cursor to stay in the pervious txtbox.

We use IE8.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get this behavior on every browser?

Comment: every browser in the sense that the company is only using Internet Explorer. But yes, it occurs on multiple desktops.

Comment: Is there any validation/AJAX type javascript or an auto post-back operating on the text box?  I've had focus issues related to these in the past...

Comment: There are validation controls on the textboxes with the tab issue (however, there are validation controls on textboxes with no tab issue)

Comment: double check your validation controls. remove them temporarily then most probably tabbing will goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem... it was caused by duplicated tab indexes... check your indexes...
at least this was my problem.

Comment: just checked the tab index, no duplicates